# Jupyter notebook how to generate continuous data based on categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have got an original data frame that has many columns such as "price" and "category name". There are about 70 categories and nearly 100,000 different prices (continuous variable). Each category in "category name" column has different range, mean and standard deviation for price.

I want to generate a new column of price from the original data. I want to generate prices based on "category name", so that the new price column still maintain the same distribution as the original data, but with random different values. How should I write the code to achieve this?

Comment: Dear kurumi, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you already written some code that you could share with us so that we can see where you are stuck?

Comment: how would you calculate it on paper? If you don't know it then there is no sense to write code.